# NVMe drive not detecting on reboot

Tags: windows-10, boot, bios, nvme

Very strange problem occurring here. A couple of days ago I turned on my PC only to find it would no longer boot to the NVMe drive. An investigation revealed that it was not being detected in the BIOS. I found this strange as I had not recently performed any updates to the BIOS or the NVMe drive's firmware. I also had not installed any Windows updates in the last few days.

Anyway, I am able to get it working, but only via the following method (btw this method is reproducable - it has worked every time I have tried it (about 6-7 times):

1. Boot PC, NVMe drive doesn't detect.
2. Shut down PC.
3. **Physically uninstall the NVMe drive from the motherboard's M.2 port**, that is, unscrew it from it's mount and remove it from the slot.
4. Reboot PC, wait for it to initialise.
5. Once it tries and boots to something (there's no bootable devices so just goes to PXE) shut down the PC.
6. **Physically reinstall the NVMe drive**.
7. Power on the PC. At this point the drive has re-detected every time without fail, and it boots to Windows normally.

I have tried removing all USB devices and all SATA devices, makes no difference. Removing the power from the mobo also does nothing.

System specs:

- NVMe drive: Samsung 970 EVO 1TB
- Motherboard: ASUS TUF B450-M Gaming with BIOS update 2006 (latest)
- CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 1700
- RAM: 16GB Hyper-X DDR-2400 (2x8GB)
- Video: Aorus GTX1060 6GB
- PSU: Corsair RM750x (plugged into an APC ES700 UPS)
- OS: Windows 10 Pro 2004

The only thing I can think of is that something is not being reset in either the NVMe drive or the BIOS causing it to stay in some kind of state that makes it undetectable. Removing it from the M.2 slot causes whatever the problem is to resolve, maybe by properly shutting down the drive or setting something in the BIOS...just making some guesses here because I'm at a loss.

Can anyone suggest what the problem might be and how to resolve it? I don't see taking the drive out and putting it back in every time as being a long-term solution.

Comment: There may be something related to power states. Or maybe your BIOS settings reset at a point ??

Comment: Resetting is the thing that could make the BIOS not detect it if something must be enabled for it to be visible. Check the power settings in the BIOS to see if there are any abnormal settings. Also make sure the physical contacts are fine (and clean them.

Comment: @tascatorials Same here but without  steps 3-4. For my case, it's enough to unplug the drive, then to wait few minutes, install again, and voila. It possible not to wait, if turn off the power supply switch. Would you like to share what was the end of your story?